# Changing settings in multiple VS project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, settings, projects-and-solutions

Is there any way to change settings for multiple projects in a Visual Studio 2008 C++ solution?

For example, adding a library dependancy for all the projects, or ignoring a specific warning.

I am aware being able to change some global settings in the IDE itself, but I'm looking for settings which will be stored in the solution/project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Property Manager* tab the *Add New project property sheet* context menu entry allows you to specify lots of settings to any project including the property sheet.

When another project requires these settings use the *Add existing property sheet* context menu.